# What are multi-hop relational paths?

Tags: recommender-system, knowledge-graph

What are multi-hop relational paths in the context of knowledge graphs (KGs)?

I tried looking it up online, but didn't find a simple explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before trying to explain this term in your context, let me briefly describe the term in other contexts.

In computer networking, the term "hop" refers to a node (e.g. a router) that a packet goes through before reaching its destination from its source. In a multi-hop situation, you have several nodes involved in the process of sending the packet from the source to the destination.

A [knowledge graph](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.02320.pdf) is a graph that accumulates and conveys knowledge of the real world, where nodes represent entities of interest and edges relations between those entities.

So, multi-hop relational paths are probably relational paths involving more than one node or edge in the knowledge graph.

*But what do we mean by "relational"?*

If you are familiar with the basics of databases, the word "relational" shouldn't be so unfamiliar. In fact, there the so-called [relational databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database), [relational models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) and [relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra). Intuitively, the word "relational" is used to denote what you think it denotes, i.e. relations. See also [What a relational database is](https://www.oracle.com/database/what-is-a-relational-database/) by Oracle.

*And what is a path?*

In section 2.2.3 of the tutorial [Knowledge Graphs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.02320.pdf#page=10), Aidan Hogan et al. provide a description of a path (expressions) in the context of knowledge graphs

> Navigational graph patterns. A key feature that distinguishes graph query languages is the ability to include path expressions in queries. A path expression $r$ is a regular expression that allows matching arbitrary-length paths between two nodes, which is expressed as a regular path query $(x,r,y)$, where $x$ and $y$ can be variables or constants (or even the same term).